# Which of the following representations of Karnaugh map is 'better'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

I usually come across two representations of Karnaugh maps in books and on the web as shown in the figure. The difference is whether the higher order variables are on the rows or on the columns. I would like to know if there is any particular reason to choose one over the other.

[image: Two representations of Karnaugh map]

Comment: No, there is no particular reason. The matrix is just transposed and will have the same features in both of the representations. You will still be able to find common states and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular representation which is better as @Emil pointed out.